# What is causing this NullPointerException?

Tags: clojure

I'm using Project Euler questions to help me learn clojure, and I've run into an exception I can't figure out.  nillify and change-all are defined at the bottom for reference.

```
(loop [the-vector (vec (range 100))
       queue      (list 2 3 5 7)]
    (if queue
        (recur (nillify the-vector (first queue)) (next queue))
        the-vector))
```

This throws a NullPointerException, and I can't figure out why.  The only part of the code I can see that *could* throw such an exception is the call to nillify, but it doesn't seem like queue ever gets down to just one element before the exception is thrown---and even if queue were to become empty, that's what the if statement is for.

Any ideas?

"given a vector, a value, and a list of indices, return a vector w/everthing @     indice=value"

```
(defn change-all [the-vector indices val]
    (apply assoc the-vector (interleave indices (repeat (count indices) val))))
```

"given a vector and a val, return a vector in which all entries with indices equal to    multiples of val are nilled, but leave the original untouched"

```
(defn nillify [coll val]
    (change-all coll (range (* 2 val) (inc (last coll)) val) nil))
```

Comment: Can you include the NPE stack trace?

Comment: Also, I fixed one presumed missing parens at the end of the first line but the loop body still seems messed up.

Comment: The second line in the loop; `queue (list (2 3 5 7))]` should be `queue (list 2 3 5 7)]`. But that used to throw a `ClassCastException` and not a `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem sexpr is

```
(inc (last coll))
```

You're changing the contents of the vector, you can't use this to determine the length anymore. Instead:

```
(count coll)
```

As a matter of style, use let bindings:

```
(defn change-all [the-vector indices val]
  (let [c (count indices)
        s (interleave indices (repeat c val))]
    (apply assoc the-vector s)))

(defn nillify [coll val]
  (let [c (count coll)
        r (range (* 2 val) c val)]
    (change-all coll r nil)))

(loop [the-vector (vec (range 100))
       [f & r]    '(2 3 5 7)]
  (if r
     (recur (nillify the-vector f) r)
     the-vector))
```

Comment: Wow.  Can't believe I didn't realize that.  Thanks a ton!  And thanks for the style pointer.